# SQL Max won't work?

Tags: sql

This is a really simple question, I'm sure but. I have a very basic query

```
Select MAX(ExposureYear) AS YEAR,
        totalvalue

FROM [dbo].[DetailsView]
```

I want it to return two records for 2012 but this is the result I get:

```
2009    647564
2009    818418
2009    818481
2012    8465153
2009    11739239
2012    22310900
2009    39305433
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect and should cause an error regarding `totalvalue` in the `select` clause.  It should not run.  (Even in MySQL, which supports the syntax, it would only return one row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is more like:

```
Select ExposureYear, totalvalue
FROM [dbo].[DetailsView]
where ExposureYear = (select MAX(ExposureYear) from DetailsView);
```

If the view is expensive, then you can instead use window functions:

```
select ExposureYear, totalvalue
from (select v.*, max(ExposureYear) over () as maxey
      from [dbo].[DetailsView] v
     ) v
where ExposureYear = maxey;
```

Answer (score 1):

MAX does not work in that way, you want something like:

```
select * from [dbo].[DetailsView] where exposureyear = 
(select max(exposureyear) from [dbo].[DetailsView])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ExposureYear AS YEAR, totalvalue
FROM [dbo].[DetailsView]
WHERE ExposureYear = (SELECT MAX(ExposureYear) From FROM [dbo].[DetailsView])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
select ExposureYear AS YEAR, totalvalue from [dbo].[DetailsView] where ExposureYear = 
(select max(ExposureYear) from [dbo].[DetailsView])
```

Answer (score 0):

If Your "**exposureYear**" column is `varchar data type` then change it to `int` it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dude keep it simple just add a group by.

```
Select MAX(ExposureYear) AS YEAR, totalvalue
FROM [dbo].[DetailsView]
GROUP BY totalvalue
```